# Javascript Function Constructor from String failes to run

Tags: javascript, string, function

Could someone help me understand why new Function does not work here?

```
var fn = data["callback"]; // String with value: function() { anotherFunctionToRun(); }
var foo = new Function("return ("+fn+")");
foo();

alert(foo) // returns function anonymous() { return function () {anotherFunctionToRun();}; }
alert(foo()) // function () { anotherFunctionToRun(); }

foo(); // Wont do anything
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Your call to foo() is just returning the function object, but not invoking it.  Try this:

foo()();

Answer (score 0):

You're creating `foo` as a function which returns another function. Whenever you execute `foo()`, it'll return a function.

```
foo(); // returns a function, but appears to do nothing

alert(foo) // prints definition of foo, which is the complete function body
alert(foo()) // shows you the function body of the function returned by foo

foo(); // returns a function, but appears to do nothing
```

To run `anotherFunctionToRun`, you would need to execute the returned function:

```
var anotherFoo = foo();
anotherFoo(); // should execute anotherFunctionToRun
```

Or just don't wrap the `data["callback"]` code in a function returning function to begin with.